# 符号なし64bit変数のビット演算の挙動がおかしい

Tags: c, アルゴリズム

次の64bit変数 `unsigned __int64` にビット演算を行うプログラムについて質問です。
XORで初期化してから6番目のビット反転 `val |= (1<<5);` を行うと、37 番目も一緒に反転するのはなぜなのでしょうか。
コンパイラとして MSCV や bcc32 を使っても同じ挙動でした。OS は Windows10 64bit です。
32bit変数 `unsigned __int32` では、期待した挙動になるのですが、64bit変数で意図した動作にならず困っています。どうぞよろしくお願いします。

```
#include <stdio.h>

void b_printf( unsigned __int64 x )
{
    int i;
    
    for( i=0; i<64; i++ ){
        ( x & (1<<i) ) ? printf( "1" ) : printf( "0" );
        if( (i+1)%10 == 0 ) printf( " " );
        }
    printf( "\n" );
}

int main( void )
{
    unsigned __int64 val;
    
    val ^= val;
    b_printf( val );
    
    val |= (1<<5);
    b_printf( val );
    
    return 0;
}
```

実行結果

```
0000000000 0000000000 0000000000 0000000000 0000000000 0000000000 0000
0000010000 0000000000 0000000000 0000000100 0000000000 0000000000 0000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> ( x & (1<<i) ) ? printf( "1" ) : printf( "0" );
> ```

こんな感じにすべきなのでは？

```
( x & ((__int64)1 << i) ) ? printf( "1" ) : printf( "0" );
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます、たしかに動きました！まさか表示関数側の問題だと認識してなかったので、完全に盲点でした…ありがとうございました！

Comment: まぁ，正直，私には「何が起こっているのか」正しくはわからない（知らない）のですが．
例えば `1 << i` で iが32以上(?) の場合は（言語仕様上）どうなるのか？　とか，`__int64` が `int` に変換される際はどうなるのか？　とか…

Comment: おそらく `val |= (1<<5);` のところでも同じような話があるのかもしれない，と思う．（ `__int64` と `int` との演算はどうなる？ `__int64` になるならOKだが）
そこらへんのルールをきちんと把握した上で書かれているなら問題ないですが，私みたいに不安がある場合は `(__int64)` みたいなのを明示的に書くのが良いのかな．

Comment: ビット演算全般で "1" が普通の int 型になって情報が落ちているのは全然注意してなかったので、明示的にキャストして本番コードにちょうど反映させたところです。おかげさまで期待どうりの挙動になっています。このあたりの挙動に対する言語仕様は全然詳しくないので、```sizeof`` で実験してみました。

Comment: ```unsigned __int64 val``` に対して、とりあえず型サイズだけ見ると ```sizeof( val )``` は8バイト、```sizeof( 1<<val)``` は4バイト、```sizeof(val<<1)```は8バイト、```sizeof(1+val), sizeof(1*val)``` は8バイトだったので、シフト演算では左の変数のサイズになるようです。AND、OR の結果も大きな型に合わせる挙動でした。

Comment: シフトされる値が32ビットだと、シフト量は32の剰余になっているような挙動ですね。たしか x64 アセンブリのシフト命令がそういう挙動だった気がします。C言語的にはシフト量が大きすぎる場合は未定義動作だと思います。

Comment: なるほど…勉強になりました！状況によっては簡単に未定義動作になってしまいそうなので気をつけていきます。ビット演算触ってからこういうハードウェアとソフトウェアの繋がりをダイレクトに感じらる局面が多くてちょっと感動しました